# Google Cloude Firestore : How to fetching only document ids of a subcollection/collection?

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-firestore

My Fs structure:

- Collection: Quiz
  -- id
  -- title
  -- content
  -- questions   (Sub-collection)

Now in my application, I need to jump to specific question, but I dont want to get ALL QUESTIONS DOCUMENTS INCLUDING CONTENTS in the sub-collection (lose a lot of money ^^ )

So, Do we have any solutions to fetching ONLY DOCUMENT Ids in the sub-collection?

Note: I am using ReactJs, Mobx and Firestore for stacks.

Answer (score 0):

**When you read from a collection, you always get back the matching documents. There is no way to just read the keys of a collection in Firestore.**

If you find you need this regularly, consider adding a second collection where you keep minimal documents (e.g. just a single field) for each key. A read of that collection will consume the least bandwidth that I can think of.